# Are dynamic arrays allocated contiguously in memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, heap-memory

`int* arr = new int[5];`

Are the values of the array pointed by `arr` allocated contiguously in the heap?

Thanks.

Comment: `int *arr = int[5]` is incorrect - you left out the keyword `new`.    The elements of the array are contiguous in memory.    Among other things, that is why pointer arithmetic works.     The "heap" is an antiquated term that refers to a particular memory model - which is not required to be used by all implementations.

Comment: How could it possibly work if it weren't contiguous? You have to be able to index it, do pointer arithmetic, etc.

Comment: Objects with dynamic storage duration aren't necessarily allocated on a heap. In practice they probably are, but it's not a requirement in the language.

Comment: @Barmar would it be the same even if it was a multidimensional array? I am thinking perhaps one level is contiguous but the each level may not be contiguous with another

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The right syntax for a dynamic array is `int* arr = new int[5];`. Yes, it will be allocated contiguously.

This is not a recommended way of using an array. If you know array size at compile time and it is not too large, make it local: `int arr[5];` or `std::array<int,5> arr;`. Otherwise, use `std::vector<int> arr(5);`. `new` should be rarely used in modern C++.

Edit:
Genuine multi-dimensional dynamic arrays allocated like these

```
int (*arr2)[6] = new int[5][6];
int (*arr3)[6][7] = new int[5][6][7];
```

are also contiguous.
But if you use a 1D array of pointers and allocate dynamic array to each pointer:

```
int** arrp = new int*[5];
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    arrp[i] = new int[6];
```

then data in `arrp` is not contiguous, even though you can use it the same way as `arr2`, e.g.:

```
arrp[2][3] = 4
```

Comment: Would it be the same even if it was a multidimensional array? I am thinking perhaps one level is contiguous but the each level may not be contiguous with another

Comment: Yes, if it indeed multidimensional array rather than an array of pointers.

Comment: Sorry just to clarify, you're saying that multidimensional dynamic array is indeed also stored contiguously in memory right

Comment: All single allocations will be continuous -- otherwise pointer arithmetic would break. I suspect where your confusion arises is when you think about allocating *pointers* and then allocating blocks to assign to each pointer. In that case the block of pointers will be contiguous, but there is no reason for any of the subsequent allocations to be contiguous with that (they are separate allocations)